# Pandas DataFrame - replace substring in column if a substring exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update DataFrame column names if a substring exists within the column name, however I only need to update the substring, retaining all information either side of it.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

lookup = [('abc_param_one_new', 'param_one'), 
          ('abc_param_two_new', 'param_two'), 
          ('abc_param_three_new', 'param_three')]

d = {'p1_abc_param_ONE_new1': [1,2],
     'p2_abc_param_one_new2': [45,3],
    'p3_abc_Param_One_new3': [76,5],
    'p4_abc_param_two_new1': [4321,6],
    'p5_abc_param_Two_new2': [3,2],
    'p6_abc_param_THREE_new1': [6,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# make all lowercase 
df.columns = [x.lower() for x in df.columns]
```

I am trying to use the lookup var (this could be a different format though) to search and replace the substring within each column name.

e.g.

```
'p1_abc_param_ONE_new1' -> 'p1_param_one1'
```

I can do this primitively looping over the lookup and the checking for each column header, but can't manage to replace the substring.

Additionally it feels that the nested loop approach is not very efficient. Is there a more pythonic way to do this perhaps using built in pandas methods and/or list comprehensions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with replacement dictionary

```
repl = {fr'(?i){k}': v for k, v in lookup}
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().replace(repl, regex=True)
```

---

```
   p1_param_one1  p2_param_one2  p3_param_one3  p4_param_two1  p5_param_two2  p6_param_three1
0              1             45             76           4321              3                6
1              2              3              5              6              2                5
```

Comment: Note this is is much less efficient than using `str.replace` with a single regex as I suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71527066/16343464). `replace` will test all the items in the dictionary for all the columns!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex and [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
dic = dict(lookup)
pat = '|'.join(dic)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(pat, lambda x: dic.get(x.group(0)), regex=True)
```

output (`df.columns`):

```
Index(['p1_param_one1', 'p2_param_one2', 'p3_param_one3', 'p4_param_two1',
       'p5_param_two2', 'p6_param_three1'],
      dtype='object')
```